# Hostapd only starts when second network adapter is disconnected

Tags: boot, kali-linux, wireless-access-point, network-interface, hostapd

I run [hostapd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostapd) and [dnsmasq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dnsmasq) on boot to start an access point. This works when I don't have a second network adapter connected. But when I boot with an extra adapter it doesn't start.

It seems like the problem is that `wlan0` is a different adapter everytime the Raspberry Pi starts. So hostapd tries to use a different adapter every time.

It works by just plugging the second adapter in after boot. Anyone know how I set a standard interface name so it always picks the right adapter?